# how do I access the background color for a linear gradient in a swiftui component

Tags: swift, swiftui

I don't really understand where .background magically appears from in swiftui.  I have this code that works:

```swift
Text(title)
    .frame(height: 60)
    .frame(maxWidth: 500)
    .background( .background )
```

but this code doesn't - and I don't know how to *make* it work:

```swift
Text(title)
    .frame(height: 60)
    .frame(maxWidth: 500)
    .background(
        LinearGradient(
            colors: [color, .background], 
            startPoint: .topLeading,
            endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
```

I understand that .background is coming from shapestyle - but I don't know how to essentially access it from the gradient context where it's not appearing all by itself.
any ideas?

Comment: `.background` is probably a `some View`, definitely not a `Color`... are you trying to have a gradient that fades into the background color?

Comment: yes - but I am in a zstack - so I need to _cover_ what's behind it - so I can't just fade to transparent... but I'm also just curious at how to get the current background color

Comment: Well `background` is whatever you set it to be... and also it might not even be a `Color`. You can put in anything as the `background`, even `LinearGradient` as shown in your code